# How to assign a back end data value to a string variable in AngularJS?

Tags: factory

I was trying to define one sort of global variable which value will be reflecting in 2/3 different templates (directives). For that I used angular factory as follows:

```
app.factory('MyService', function ($http) {
    return {    
        firstNumber: function (){       
            //return selectedNumber = "200";

            var selectedNumber = "";

            var selectedNumber = $http.get("/count.do").success(function (data) {
                console.log('First Number: ', data[0].count)
            });

            return selectedNumber;
        }
    };
});
```

As you can see 'selectedNumber' is that common variable. Problem is when I am hard coding the value as "200" and from controller calling as follows:

```
//Init Number
$scope.selectedNumber= MyService.firstNumber();
```

This whole process is working fine. But as soon as I am trying to get the value from back end (which you can see above) getting {} object.

I did some research on this and understanding that my concept on Angular object and String manipulation is not clear...can anyone please help me to understand the mistake I am doing and to resolve this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i got my expected outcome by using 'callback' service as follows:

In my factory i just called the '$http.get':

```
app.factory('MyService', function ($http) {
    return {    
        firstNumber: function (){                   
            $http.get("/count.do").success(callback);
        }
    };
});
```

And then from controller i received the data and assigned as follows:

```
//Init Number
MyService.firstNumber(function(data) {
    $scope.selectedNumber = data[0].count;
});
```

I don't know whether it is a good solution or what, will really appreciate for any comment on this solution plz.

Thanks